# Another video dismiss left audio when concat two videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to concat two mp4 file `header.mp4` and `body.mp4`. And I use below command.

```
ffmpeg -i header.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i body.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
```

Then I concat them.

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

The output file has right duration however the audio of `body.mp4` is only remained , in another word the video of `body.mp4` dismiss in `output.mp4`.

If I remove `-c copy` in the third command, I got right result but it takes too long time. What's wrong?

## EDIT

`ffmpeg -i header.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
        built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --disable-jack --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree
        libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'header.mp4':
Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf57.52.100
Duration: 00:00:04.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 644 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 632 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(zho): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

And `ffmpeg -i body.mp4`：

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
        built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --disable-jack --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree
        libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'body.mp4':
Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isommp42
creation_time   : 2017-03-01T09:47:27.000000Z
Duration: 00:01:33.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 241 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 112 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2017-03-01T09:47:27.000000Z
handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2017-03-01T09:47:27.000000Z
handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
```

Comment: Show complete output of `ffmpeg -i header.mp4` and `ffmpeg -i body.mp4`

Comment: Do you mean first and second command ?

Comment: You can also show the complete output of your two commands, yes.

Comment: @LiJianixn I meant just `ffmpeg -i header.mp4` and `ffmpeg -i body.mp4` (or `ffmpeg -i header.mp4 -i body.mp4` if you prefer but make sure not to forget both `-i` options). It will show required info about your inputs and your `ffmpeg`. This request often confuses users. The output from your first and second commands will suffice too, but the output will be much longer and I don't need that extra info.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

To concatenate your inputs should have the same formats and parameters. In your case the video has different frame rates and the audio has different sample rates.

## Solutions

You can either:

- Re-encode one of the inputs to match the other, then use the **concat demuxer**, or
- use some filters to fix the differences then concatenate using the **concat filter** all in one command.
- I almost never recommend using the **concat protocol** as the demuxer or filter are usually better choices for most users.

### concat demxer

Advantage is that only one video is re-encoded instead of both, and the process may be faster than using the concat filter.

To match `header.mp4` to `body.mp4` first re-encode `header.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -i header.mp4 -r 24 -ar 44100 -profile:v main -video_track_timescale 90k header_2.mp4
```

The make a text file, such as `input.txt`, that contains the names of the files you want to concatenate:

```
file header_2.mp4
file body.mp4
```

Finally, use the concat demuxer:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

### concat filter

Advantage is if you are going to concatenate a multitude of disparate sources you can use the same command options for them all (assuming your filterchain is using the appropriate filters).

```
ffmpeg -i header.mp4 -i body.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=24[v0];[v0][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

The concat filter will automatically select a common pixel format for video streams, and a common sample format, sample rate and channel layout for audio streams, so if you are content with letting it do that you don't need to deal with those. Otherwise, add more filters.

#### More info

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Concat](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)
- [FFmpeg concat demuxer documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat)
- [FFmpeg concat filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat)

Comment: Can you explain `ffmpeg -i header.mp4 -r 24 -ar 44100 -profile:v main header_2.mp4` ?

Comment: @LiJianixn These options will match the differing `header.mp4` parameters to `body.mp4`. `-r` changes the frame rate: `header.mp4` is 30000/1001 (aka "29.97"), `body.mp4` is 24. `-ar` changes the audio sample rate: `header.mp4` is 48000, `body.mp4` is 44100. `-profile:v` manually selects the H264 profile: `header.mp4` is High profile, `body.mp4` is Main profile.

Comment: `concat demxer` does not work for me.

Comment: The duration of `output.mp4` is 11:52.

Comment: @LiJianixn Without more info I cannot suggest anything. Show info for each input file: `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2`. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.

Comment: Do you need which info of input file? `header.mp4` or `body.mp4`? I have already post info .

Comment: @LiJianixn I was assuming you re-encoded `header.mp4` to match the properties of `body.mp4`, so only the info of the new `header.mp4` will suffice. If you tried the concat demuxer without fixing `header.mp4` then it will not work because all inputs need to have the same properties.

Comment: I have fixed header.mp4 using `ffmpeg -i header.mp4 -r 24 -ar 44100 -profile:v main header_2.mp4`

Comment: @LiJianixn Show output of `ffmpeg -i header_2.mp4`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75383/discussion-between-lijianixn-and-lordneckbeard).